# Using Core Text options with TextKit (like CTLineBoundsOptions)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-text, textkit

Is there a way to use advanced Core Text options with TextKit (2)?

Specifically, I’m looking to enable `useHangingPunctuation` for `NSAttributedString`s that I draw in layers using TextKit 2.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctlineboundsoptions/1508952-usehangingpunctuation

Thanks!